# Create an attachment from varbinary data and make it downloadable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an Attachments table in the DB where there is a filename and filedata that is in varbinary format. On the c# end, I need to convert this data to string and depending on the MIMEType, create a downloadable .xls/.pdf file. What is the best way to do this? Can I use ActionLink to do this? I'm new to using MVC and do not have an idea of the best approach for this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bypass converting to a string and just worry about returning the correct mime type.

Check out this question:

[byte[] to File Type in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617834/byte-to-file-type-in-mvc-3)

You just need to determine the content type to set the mime type.

Comment: I know the MIME type as it is also stored in the DB for me. Thanks!

Comment: Would you happen to know how this can be done from JavaScript? I've been trying to incorporate this, however, I will have to create the links to the filenames dynamically depending on how many there are. Once the links are created, I need to do this on their click events.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use ActionLink to do this?

Yes.

> On the c# end, I need to convert this data to string and depending on
>   the MIMEType, create a downloadable .xls/.pdf file.

You add Content-Disposition (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526989(v=exchg.10).aspx) to response header.

**Content-Disposition: attachment**

Body parts designated as containing attachments require user action to be displayed. and are normally split out of the message. They are typically stored as files for subsequent access. The optional parameters for this header are: file name, creation-date, modification-date, read-date, and size.

**Content-Disposition: inline**

Inline content is displayed to the user when the message is opened. The inline body parts are to be displayed in the order they appear in the message, subject to applicable rules for multipart content type. If a multipart body part has an inline header, the inline designation applies to the multipart as a whole, not to its subparts.

Check the code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9610656/1241400

You can use `inline` for *.pdf as most browser can open it and for other file types use `attachment`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do the same kind of thing before. I would return a FileContentResult and then use Urlmon.dll to determine the mime type to pass to the File method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208.aspx, on the Controller class, with the byte[] data you got from the DB, and the mime type returned by Urlmon.dll, http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.FindMimeFromData, pinvoke.